# Do Laptops exist that allow to swap the GPU?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

I'm about to buy a new laptop computer. I might want a better NVidia GPU on my own computer in the future, and it would be great to keep that option open without buying an expensive machine right away.

I didn't find such information on any laptop available online, so I fear this generally does not exist, at least not for lower-cost models. This [PCWorld article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2923779/how-to-upgrade-graphics-in-a-laptop.html) from 2015 suggests that it's possible for some laptops made by the manufacturer Clevo.

**The question:** Are there laptop computers in the range of 1000-1300€ (-1500 USD) that allow to upgrade the GPU? If not, what would be the minimum price for such a computer, if they exist?

Comment: I can confirm that there is a [standard slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module) for laptop graphics cards, but I have no clue whether a $1500 USD laptop still uses it these days. I have seen them inside Alienware and other build-to-order gaming notebooks in the past. When the GPU is not integrated in the motherboard it will make the laptop & cooling system significantly thicker though, so a thin model almost never uses this slot.

Comment: So what's needed is enough money, time to do research and then some luck, and you end up with an exchangeable GPU. Thank you, and thanks for the link.

Comment: With an emphasis on luck! There is the possibility that the laptop you get now may not support newer MXM graphics cards due to changes in the standard or dimensions of the cards available when you decide to upgrade. (I used to work in PC building/repair and...) The only time I've seen somebody successfully change their MXM card was only a side-grade to another GPU in the same generation.

Comment: Wow. Okay, I think I'll stay away from such experiments for now.

Comment: You might be interested in eGPUs, otherwise, this is mostly an infeasible task.

Comment: Good hint, @Rubyjunk, thank you. This could actually work: There are some links on the eGPU Wiki entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#External_GPU_(eGPU)) to vendor pages, and e.g. HP here lists their compatible devices and GPUs: https://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/omenaccelerator/overview.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, this isn't really possible - as of now (2019), there are no laptops that have exchangeable GPUs that I'm aware of. However, eGPUs are a way that you can upgrade the GPU of a laptop, though they lack the portability of an inbuilt GPU and are typically rather expensive.

Comment: Accepted, because eGPU's are something that one can find vendor information about and where you can avoid uncertainty whether it will work or not. Still, swapping GPU's 'might be possible', with luck involved, as @Romen said.  -    Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not upgrade your laptop's gpu but you can make custom laptop according to your preference. I am providing a link below you can visit if you want to make custom laptop.

https://www.originpc.com/

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is specifically about adding another GPU *later*, but buying a cheap-ish computer now.